# Extracting value from nested array and struct spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a schema like the below. I was wondering what is the best way in spark to select the elements seat and drive then cast it into a string. I am reading this in a dataframe with spark 1.6.

```
|-- cars: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- carId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- carCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- carNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- seat: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- drive: string (nullable = true)
```

The output of cars.features as car_features in json:

```
"cars_features":[[{"seat":"Auto","drive":"Manual"}]]
```

I am trying to select "Auto" and put it into a dataframe column and "Manual" and put into another column.

current attempt returns the whole structure as:

```
+-------------------+
|car_features       |
+-------------------+
|  [[Auto,Manual]]  |
+-------------------+

col("car.features").getItem(0).as("car_features_seat")
```

Comment: so you want select `seat` and `drive` as arrays of arrays or just as an array or as rows?

Comment: I edited the question to make that more clear.

Comment: getItem("key") not 0.

Answer (score 1):

I had to drill into array twice:

```
col("car.features").getItem(0).getItem(0).getItem("seat").cast("String").as("car_features_seat")
```

This extracts "Auto"